# Haskell: What is a parser in a monadic parser?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm reading this paper regarding a [monadic parser in Haskell](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/pearl.pdf) and as a newbie I cannot understand the following construct:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a, String)])

instance Monad Parser where
  return a = Parser (\cs -> [(a,cs)])
  p >>= f  = Parser (\cs -> concat [parse (f a) cs’ |
                               (a,cs’) <- parse p cs])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse (Parser p) = p
```

It says in the text that:

> Using a deconstructor function for parsers defined by parse (Parser p) = p, the parser p >>= f first applies the parser p to the argument string cs to give a list of results of the form (a,cs’), where a is a value and cs’ is a string. For each such pair, f a is a parser which is applied to the string cs’.

Why is (f a) and not f a parser? And why is passing the 'a' necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `(>>=)`, instantiated with the monad `Parser`, has this type signature:

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
```

Hence, when defining `p >>= f`, `p` has type `Parser a` and `f` has type `a -> Parser b`. That’s why `f a` is a parser and not `f`: `f` is a function from `a` to `Parser b`s.

The reason it’s that way is that without it, we could combine parsers… but we would never be able to use the result of the previous parser in the next parse! By passing the result of the previous parser forward, we can build up data out of the results of multiple parsers, e.g.:

```
parseTwoOf :: Parser a -> Parser (a, a)
parseTwoOf p = p >>= \first -> p >>= \second -> return (first, second)
```

Comment: I’m not sure the last paragraph and code block are terribly clear, but I can’t think of a better way to explain it right now.

Comment: We can build things up with applicative parsers too, without being able to do that, but for now, most popular parsing libraries are monadic.

Comment: @dfeuer: I was more saying that that value needs to go somewhere if it’s going to be useful, because otherwise you end up with something having only the power of `>>`.

Comment: If all results are used only in the final `return`, then `Applicative` is enough: `parseTwoOf p = (,) <$> p <*> p`.

Comment: @user3237465: As I was saying to dfeuer, yes, I’m well aware `Applicative` is sufficient—I was not trying to say the power of `Monad` was necessary, but rather that if you want `>>=` to be able to do anything more than `>>` can do, you cannot discard the value of `a`.